# Visual Studio Keybind Equivalent to Control + Shift + P on VSCode in order to focus the "Search Everywhere Textbox"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to find the keybind to pass focus into the global-search textbox but to no avail:

[image: Global Searchbox]

Isn't there a keybind for VisualStudio like 'Ctrl + Shift + P' from VSCode? Do I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

In my Visual Studio it even says so in the box, but maybe that's only with the language set to German for some reason:

[image: screenshot]

The feature is called "Quick Launch", so the function used for this keyboard is called `Window.QuickLaunch`.

Comment: Thanks for tuning in. Would you be kind enough to open the options of visual studio and report back the exact name of the function? Thanks again!

Comment: In English it should be `Window.QuickLaunch` (`Fenster.Schnellstart` in German)

Comment: In case you are still having issues, make sure your VS2019 is up to date. I believe there was a bug in an earlier version where this shortcut was broken.

Comment: Understood - my bad!